# Leaflet map not showing properly in bootstrap 3.0 modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, leaflet

i have a big problem. i want to open a leaflet map in a modal.
but the map is not showing properly. the tiles are not loading.

here is the script:

https://codeply.com/p/TYUqgVvYAQ

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Open Map</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Map</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="modal-body" id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">OK</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$.getScript('http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js',function(){

 /* map settings */
 var map = new L.Map('map-canvas');
 var cloudmade = new    L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/f1376bb0c116495e8cb9121360802fb0/997/256/{z}/{x} /{y}.png', {
 attribution: 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>   contributors, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
 maxZoom: 18
 });
 map.addLayer(cloudmade).setView(new L.LatLng(41.52, -71.09), 13);


 });
```

any help much apreciated

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I think what is happening is that, when the map is created, the container width/height for your `map-canvas' element has not yet been adjusted to the width/height of the modal dialog. This causes the map size to be incorrect (smaller) than what it should be.

You can fix this by calling `map.invalidateSize()`. This will work to re-adjust the width/height bounds of the L.Map's container.

You can automatically call this by hooking into the event where the Bootstrap modal becomes shown.

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
    map.invalidateSize();
  }, 10);
 });
```

Insert this code into your JavaScript. When the modal is shown, the map will then invalidate its size. The timeout is because there may be some animation/transition time for the modal to display and be added to the DOM.

Comment: maybe you can help me out with this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404174/open-modal-with-marker-leaflet-bootstrap-3 :)

Comment: In some cases 10 milliseconds could be a very small time considering the time that takes the modal to be fully loaded. Its a good idea increase the time before invalidateSize() is called and/or put a refresh button in the modal to call that function when it gets clicked.

Comment: A 'refresh' button would certainly provide a gaurentee.

Comment: My issue wasn't modal related but still missing. I had to add a dimension to style. I choose to go with height.
`<div id='map-canvas' style='height:360px;'></div>`

Answer (score 25):

You should probably avoid using setTimeout with a randomly chosen delay. A better way using the 'shown.bs.modal' event instead of 'show.bs.modal':

```
modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        map.invalidateSize();
   }, 1);
})
```

Or use underscore's defer :

```
modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    _.defer(map.invalidateSize.bind(map));
})
```

Comment: ^ This should be the accepted answer. Additionally because the 'shown' event is fired once the modal is visible you no longer need to queue the invalidateSize() method do you? You can just use modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function () { map.invalidateSize(); }); (source: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

Comment: Yeah, this is better.

Answer (score 8):

I use this workaround:

```
.modal {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.modal[aria-hidden='false'] {
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, [you can read here](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/issues/104#issuecomment-349086565)

```
map.whenReady(() => {
    console.log('Map ready');
    setTimeout(() => {
        map.invalidateSize();
    }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried map.invalidateSize() but not fixed.

finaly it fixed by this:

```
$('#map-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(event) {});
```

In the function, put the codes related to loading the map.

Comment: This answer to an 8 year old question is not helpful: it speaks of a specific solution for someone else.

Comment: @gdvalderrama But after a few hours of searching, I found this answer that was my solution and I'm sure it will be the solution of many others.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -

```
 $('#gmap').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    //call the clear map event first
    clearMap();
    //resize the map - this is the important part for you
   map.invalidateSize(true);
   //load the map once all layers cleared
   loadMap();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

leaflet map uncorrect display on load can be solved with this :

```
  var mapid = $(this).find('[id^=leaflet-map]').attr('id');
  var map = settings.leaflet[mapid].lMap;
  map.invalidateSize();
```

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this issue: init map in main window. Then move map  to opened modal.

Answer (score 0):

First, create the map in div outside of the Moodle

```
<div>
  <div class="modal-body" id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%;height: 300px;"></div>
</div>
```

And write same js code :

```
 /* map settings */
 var map = new L.Map('map-canvas');
 var cloudmade = new    L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/f1376bb0c116495e8cb9121360802fb0/997/256/{z}/{x} /{y}.png', {
 attribution: 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>   contributors, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
 maxZoom: 18
 });
 map.addLayer(cloudmade).setView(new L.LatLng(41.52, -71.09), 13);


 });
```

Then move the map to the Moodle :

```
$('#map-canvas').appendTo('.modal-body');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this `map.invalidateSize()` code inside the `shown.bs.modal` custom event callback. Then no need any `setTimeout()` function.

```js
$('#yourModalElementId').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    map.invalidateSize();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

for vue.js and nuxt.js developers , probably it's because of using **v-show** or **v-if**
but you shouldn't use v-if and instead use v-show.
after that the only thing u need is using client-only tag like this:

```
<client-only>
<div v-show="someVariable" id="vShowOrVIfExample">
<div id="map-wrap" style="height: 100vh">
   <l-map :zoom=13 :center="[55.9464418,8.1277591]">
     <l-tile-layer url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"></l-tile-layer>
     <l-marker :lat-lng="[55.9464418,8.1277591]"></l-marker>
   </l-map>
 </div>
</div>
</client-only>
```