# open modal with marker leaflet bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, leaflet, marker

i got the map showing in the modal working. now i have a new problem. i have different objects and i will store the coordinates for the marker in the id.

like this:

```
<a href="#eintrag" id="[48.20682894891699, 16.370315551757812]" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Open Map</a>
```

this also opens the modal with the map.
then i have this:

```
    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: new L.LatLng(48.20682894891699, 16.370315551757812),
        zoom: 14,
        maxBounds: bounds
    });

    jQuery(document).on("click", "a", function (event) {
        id =jQuery(this).attr('id') || '';
        console.log(id);                    
    }); 

    L.marker(id).addTo(map);
```

can anyone help me out with this? - the map is blank :(
help much apreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to add a Marker to the map? Such as a point location on the map? I'm not sure what your approach is, but you certainly do not want to put the Lat/Lng inside of an element's ID. There is a better way to whatever you are trying to achieve. Please be more specific so I can make a recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Two things for starters:

1. You want to use `id` when it's `undefined` (you create it when you click `a`)
2. You can't use string `id` to init marker, you can fix it using `eval()`

[Is this what you wanted?](http://jsfiddle.net/6EuUn/)

BTW. For storing data you can use `data-id` instead of `id`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the value as string, try eval() -

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: new L.LatLng(48.20682894891699, 16.370315551757812),
    zoom: 14,
    maxBounds: bounds
});

jQuery(document).on("click", "a", function (event) {
    id =jQuery(this).attr('id');
    console.log(id);                    
}); 

L.marker(eval(id)).addTo(map);
```