# Leaflet map freezing in bootstrap 3.0 modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to load map in bootstrap modal but map appear partly, it's also freezing so I can't select any region. Despite of using map.invalidateSize() my problem is still resisting. Is there anybody to make it work in bootstrap modal or any other kind of modal?

[image: leaflet-modal]

here is my code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var LbsConfig = {
        Url:'https://map.ghasedakbahar.ir:6443/arcgis/rest/services/iran/FeatureServer/0',
        View: [35.6970, 51.4079],
        MapID: 'map-id',
        Color: {
            Default: '#9ab9ff',
            Selected: '#ff0659'
        }
    };

    var map = LbsMap();
    LbsShowNew(map, function (regions) {
        var maxRegions = 5;
        var errRegions = 'The number of areas is more than 5 areas';
        if (regions.length > maxRegions) {
            alert(errRegions);
            return;
        }
        jQuery('#Regions').val(regions.join(','));
        jQuery('#count-selected').html(regions.length);
    });

    $('#myMap').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            map.invalidateSize();
        }, 10);
    });

</script>
```

```css
#map-id {
        padding: 0;
        width: auto;
        height: 400px;
    }
```

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myMap" role="dialog" style="margin-top:70px">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content font-yekan">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">'SendSmsDetail'</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
                <div id="map-id"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 0):

I remember having the same problem before. There is a lot of similar problem on internet and maybe this one can help you :

[Leaflet map not showing properly in bootstrap 3.0 modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400713/leaflet-map-not-showing-properly-in-bootstrap-3-0-modal)

> I think what is happening is that, when the map is created, the
>   container width/height for your `map-canvas' element has not yet been
>   adjusted to the width/height of the modal dialog. This causes the map
>   size to be incorrect (smaller) than what it should be.
>
> You can fix this by calling map.invalidateSize(). This will work to
>   re-adjust the width/height bounds of the L.Map's container.
>
> You can automatically call this by hooking into the event where the
>   Bootstrap modal becomes shown.
>
> ```
> $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
>   setTimeout(function() {
>     map.invalidateSize();
>   }, 10);
>  });
> ```
>
> Insert this code into your JavaScript. When the modal is shown, the
>   map will then invalidate its size. The timeout is because there may be
>   some animation/transition time for the modal to display and be added
>   to the DOM.

Comment: Can you try to provide a working jsfiddle link ? So I could try on it and see your problem ?